# Style script output within html

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following script inside html, but the output inside html is without style.

How can I best style the script output so as it fits within the existing html structure?

I thought this may be achieved by getting the output by id, but have not figured that out.

```
<script>
    var myArray = [
        "<ul><p>Alef</p><p>1</p>",
        "<ul><p>Bet</p><p>2</p>"
    ];

    var randomItem = myArray[Math.floor(Math.random()*myArray.length)];

    document.body.innerHTML += randomItem;
</script>
```

Comment: The HTML in your array is invalid. A `<p>` cannot be a child of a `<ul>`. Only a `<li>` can

Comment: Instead of setting `innerHTML` on the body, try creating a new element that you can then add styles to. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement

Comment: @scott How would this look in practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of setting innerHTML on the body, try creating a new element that you can then add styles to, and then adding that element to the body.

```
const randomItemElement = document.createElement("div");
randomItemElement.innerHTML = randomItem;
randomItemElement.style.color = "blue";

document.body.appendChild(randomItemElement);
```

You can also create a CSS class and set that on your element instead of setting individual properties, e.g. `randomItemElement.classList.add("myClass")`

Comment: How would I specify 'max-width'? The dash seems to make problems.

Comment: `.style.maxWidth = "100px";` works